Chart.js Line Graph not displaying data for total Revenue for the past 15 days
I've been debugging this some time now and probably 2 hours now. I want to display the line graph of chart.js the revenue for the past 15 days.
I have a function to get the ajax result for the previous days. This is the js script I made.
// Function to fetch revenue data from PHP script
function fetchRevenueData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../config/tables/semi_weekly_revenue.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var revenueValues = labels.map(function(date) {
                return data[date] || 0; 
            });
        
            myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data = revenueValues;
            myLineChart.update();

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('Error fetching revenue data:', error);
        }
    });
}

the line graph:
// Area Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels, 
        datasets: [{
            label: "Revenue",
            lineTension: 0.3,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointHitRadius: 50,
            pointBorderWidth: 2,
            data: [],
        }],
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                time: {
                    unit: 'date'
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                },
                ticks: {
                    maxTicksLimit: 7
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 40000,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5
                },
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)",
                }
            }],
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
});

//The fetchRevenueData function will update the Linechart upon called.
fetchRevenueData();

my php query script looks like this:
 // Query to fetch total revenue for each of the past 15 days
    $query = "SELECT 
                DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
                SUM(total_amount) AS total_revenue
              FROM sales
              WHERE sale_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
              GROUP BY date
              ORDER BY date";

    $stmt = $pdo->query($query);

   // Fetch revenue data and populate the revenueData array
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $revenueData[$row['date']] = $row['total_revenue'];
    }

   // Return revenue data as JSON
   echo json_encode($revenueData);

Did I miss something? I've read the documentation about data passing and maybe I miss something. I'm still learning JavaScript now. Thanks!
I expect the result to show the Line Graph similar to the bar graph but it will on semi-weekly Forecast of revenue for the past 15 days.

what does console.log(data) tell you? what's the value of labels?

Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please read how to ask a good question.
